# Docker MERN Deployment - hot reload is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, deployment, hot-reload

im moving my repository to a docker container with single services and everything seems to work as expected except the hot reloading of the react development environment. Perhaps is it necessary to use a volume for client-development service? Code:

Dockerfile (react):

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /client

ENV PATH /client/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  server: 
    build: 
      context: ./server
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on: 
      - db
  client-development:
    build: 
      context: ./client
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks: 
      - default
    depends_on: 
      - server
  db:
    image: "mongo"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db

networks: 
  default:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Your development and deployment environments can be different, and that's fine.  I'd recommend using your existing host-based Node environment for day-to-day development, even if you're ultimately deploying via Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a bind mount in order to do a mirroring among the host machine and the container which is running your react app, e.g.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /react-starter-kit
COPY . .
RUN npm i
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  starter:
    build: .
    image: react-starter-kit
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules:/react-starter-kit/node_modules
      - ./src:/react-starter-kit/src
```